# Do any of the major cloud providers offer machine-readable pricing information?

Tags: cloud

I was wanting to write an app to compare various cloud provider's pricing information. However, I need the data to start. Do AWS/Azure/Google provide a spreadsheet or a database of their pricing information by service type? I know they show you the prices on their websites but I'm looking for an easy to import file or folder's worth of files.

I looked online but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Only a guess!!! I suspect they do not provide what you are asking for, specifically so that people cannot do what you are proposing: price compare using apple-to-apple comparison. ;)